# How can I get the value(s) of the selected item(s) of CheckBoxList using Jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, checkbox, selectedvalue

If I have the following CheckBoxList

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="typeCheckBoxList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Student</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Parent</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Educational</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3">Specialist </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Using Jquery i want to get the values of the selected items, I use the following code

```
$('#<%= typeCheckBoxList.ClientID %> input:checked').each(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
   alert($(this).next('label').text());
});
```

`$(this).val()` always returns "`on`" and I can't return values such as `0 ,1`, etc.
 **Is there any way to do that ?**

*EDIT : Rendered Markup:*

```
<table id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList" class="listVertical" border="0"> 
  <tr> 
    <td>
      <input id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_0" type="checkbox" name="RegisterationWUC1$typeCheckBoxList$0" />
      <label for="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_0">Student</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_1" type="checkbox" name="RegisterationWUC1$typeCheckBoxList$1" />
      <label for="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_1">Parent</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_2" type="checkbox" name="RegisterationWUC1$typeCheckBoxList$2" />
      <label for="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_2">Educational</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_3" type="checkbox" name="RegisterationWUC1$typeCheckBoxList$3" />
      <label for="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_3">Specialist </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_4" type="checkbox" name="RegisterationWUC1$typeCheckBoxList$4" />
      <label for="RegisterationWUC1_typeCheckBoxList_4">other</label>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered markup?

Comment: i post you rendered and i notice that value attribute not exist

Comment: Which version of ASP.Net are you running? It does render here, but the quick test I ran was using ASP.Net 4, which looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FQhKV/

Comment: I use Asp.net 2.0 .. i also tried it in IE and Chrome and i got same result

Comment: The reason this wasn't rendered, I'm somewhat guessing here, is all the server-side cares about is that the check is even present in a postback, it won't be if it's not checked.  So, to do everything it needs server-side, it's not required.  I added a way to get what you want client-side, unfortunately the rendering isn't correct until 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.Net 2.0 doesn't render this appropriately (it's intended purpose is to get the values server-side) you can do a bit of hackery.  In the code-behind, do something like this:

```
foreach (ListItem li in typeCheckBoxList.Items)
  li.Attributes.Add("data-value", li.Value);
```

Then your markup will look like this (ignore the shorter names, my test wasn't in another named container, and it doesn't matter one bit for the question at hand):

```
<table id="typeCheckBoxList"> 
  <tr> 
    <td>
      <span data-value="0">
        <input id="typeCheckBoxList_0" type="checkbox" name="H$M$typeCheckBoxList$0" />
        <label for="typeCheckBoxList_0">Student</label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span data-value="1">
        <input id="typeCheckBoxList_1" type="checkbox" name="H$M$typeCheckBoxList$1" />
        <label for="typeCheckBoxList_1">Parent</label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span data-value="2">
        <input id="typeCheckBoxList_2" type="checkbox" name="H$M$typeCheckBoxList$2" />
        <label for="typeCheckBoxList_2">Educational</label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span data-value="3">
        <input id="typeCheckBoxList_3" type="checkbox" name="H$M$typeCheckBoxList$3" />
        <label for="typeCheckBoxList_3">Specialist </label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span data-value="5">
        <input id="typeCheckBoxList_4" type="checkbox" name="H$M$typeCheckBoxList$4" />
        <label for="typeCheckBoxList_4">Other</label>
      </span>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Notice that extra `<span data-value="valueHere"></span>` wrapped around it now?  You can just use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get to the `<span>` and retrieve that value via [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like this:

```
$('#typeCheckBoxList input:checked').each(function() {
  alert($(this).closest('span').attr('data-value'));
  alert($(this).next('label').text());
});
```

[Give it a try in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UwKgV/) :)  If it helps at all. the default rendering mode for ASP.Net 4.0 *does* render the `value` in markup, as it should.  The reason for the `data-thing` format on the attribute is to be as valid as possible, these are called [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), added to the spec in HTML5, but cause no issues for this in 4.